# how to dynamically update database such that similar strings should not repeat in it

Tags: database, dynamic

I am trying to update the database dynamically.But if i enter the same string twice...it is poped twice i m trying to replace it but still not working.Can anyone help me out...

Comment: what database system? mysql? postgre? access? filemaker? poped? you won't need replace anything, if the string already exists it is already there... If you want to update the row that has a string as it's key, find it and update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about MySQL, you will need to define a primary key for the REPLACE function to work.